# how to pass database connection to a class constructer?

Tags: php

i have a class that validates user input, and i have a php connection in another file, i put require_once ('dbconnection.php') at the first of the class page because i need to access the database and validate if an email already exists through a function, i know i have to pass the database connection in the constructer but i don't know how, please help.

dbconnection.php :

```
<?php 

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "info";


try 
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=info","root","");
} 
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    die('connection error:' . $ex->getMessage());
}


?>
```

the validation class:

```
<?php
require_once ('dbconnection.php');
session_start();

class registerValidation
{
    public $password;
    public $email;
    /*pubic ???$db???*/

    public function __construct($password, $email,/*????$db???*/)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->email = $email;
        
    }

    function validate()
    {

        if ($this->password != $this->password2) {
            $_SESSION["a"] = "passwords don't match";
        } else
            unset($_SESSION["a"]);
       

 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM reg WHERE email = :email ");
         $stmt->bindParam(':email',$this->email);
         $stmt->execute();
         $row = $stmt->fetch();

         if($row){
              $_SESSION["d"]="Email address is already registered";
             }
         else
            { unset($_SESSION["d"]);}
}
```

Comment: The same as you pass `email` or `password`

Comment: i just write $db?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the reference only to the function which needs it. If you pass it to the constructor, then you have to store it in the object and bound it to the object's lifecycle:

```
function validate(PDO $db) {
 ...
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
$validator = new registerValidation($username, $pass);
if ($validaor->validate($db) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't be bound to the object's lifetime as the main reference is stored outside the class

Comment: @DarkBee Isn't WeakReference required to allow the object to be destroyed by the garbage collector?

Answer (score 0):

You pass it as you are passing the email and password.

```
    public function __construct($password, $email, $db)
    {
       $this->password = $password;
       $this->email = $email;
       $this->db = $db;  
    }
```

In the validator you can use `$this->db`. This is one way to do it.

Comment: i did this and it gave me an error :  Too few arguments to function registerValidation::__construct() 3 passed, 4 exactly expected

Comment: did you check if the ``$db`` is populated with the connection or is it empty?

Comment: do you mean if the database is not empty? then yes, that's what i understood by your question

Answer (score 0):

A general practice is using some form of dependency injection to pass a class to another class.

Your class should look like this. I also made some refactorings:

```php
<?php

require_once ('dbconnection.php');
session_start();

class RegisterValidation
{
    protected PDO $db;

    private string $email;

    private string $password;

    public function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function validate($input, $input)
    {
        $this->email = $input['email'];
        $this->password = $input['password'];
        // your validation logic
        // access $db with $this->db
    }
}

$input = [
    'email' => 'email@sample.com',
    'password' => 'password'
];

$control = new RegisterValidation($db);
$control->validate($input);
```